# JSF : Passing an Object from one backing-bean to another backing-bean

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, cdi

I am trying to figure out a solution for a small problem I have encountered whilst developing a small application. I am trying to pass an object created within one backing-bean and then later using that same object I created within another backing-bean. However, I would not like to make these backing-beans `@SessionScoped`, and preferably not use the `@ManagedBean` as I am using `CDI`for my JavaEE application.

Is there anyway I could do this using `CDI` annotations and injecting one backing-bean to another and then have the ability to access that object previously created?

As an example, refer to the below beans:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public RegisterController implements Serializable {

    User user = new User();

    // Getter and Setter methods which are populated by the JSF page
}
```

Get Object `User` created within the above bean and use it within the controller below:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public PaymentController implements Serializable {

    @Inject RegisterController registerController; // Injecting bean

    registerController.getUser().getName(); //this is null when I try access the properties of the object 'User'. I am assuming this is because @ViewScoped annotated on the 'RegisterController' class? 

    // I would like to use the User object created in 'RegisterController' here an access properties etc...
}
```

Could I use the `@Inject` annotation offered by the CDI?

**UPDATE**

Ok, so I have got the above working when I annotate the `RegisterController` with the `SessionScoped` annotation, however I do not want this Bean annotated `SessionScoped` as I will probably run into further implications down the track, such as pre-population of fields, etc... Any ideas how to implement this any other way?

Comment: @SalihErikci, `@RequestScoped` CDI annotation will not work as the Object has to last longer then a single `HTTP Request`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `@ViewScoped` is too short to the purpose and `@SessionScoped` is too long. Then why not use `@ConversationScoped`?

See [here](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/scopescontexts.html#_built_in_scopes).

Comment: I have implemented this using CDI @ConversationScoped. Thanks for your note.

Answer (score 1):

you can use in RegistrationController:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("user", user);
```

and in PaymentController:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("user");
```

this is very useful, you can save the objects you want in the map.